# How to add CSS to menu_callback page?

Tags: theming, 7

I have implemented hook_menu in my module and created a page. Now how to add CSS to this page? I have the below code inside my page_callback function, but still the css is not applied.

```
$css = "table,tr,th,td {padding: 10 !important; }";
drupal_add_css($css, 'inline');
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you've hacked D6, 'inline' only works with `drupal_add_js()`, not `drupal_add_css()`.  So, to do what you want, you need to put that line of css in a file and include that file instead.